# Jammit disable Java compression in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jammit

I'm using the jammit gem. I want disable the java compression in production mode on server. because i do the compression in my pc.

How can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your assets.yml file in config, create this line:

`compress_assets: off`

More documentation can be found here: http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/#configuration